# Source code to google sheets functions

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, stockquotes

I'm trying to get stock quotes from Yahoo Finance or Google Finance.

I know Google sheet's `IMPORTXML` function can basically do this, but into a spreadsheet. I want to get the price of the stock and then have a program decide to buy / sell / anything else.

So I'm trying to find the JavaScript source code for the `IMPORTXML` function. I think it's JavaScript but I haven't actually found it so I don't actually know. Also if you know of another way to accomplish this I'm open to it!

Comment: I think this is an XY problem. You don't really want that source, you want to accomplish something. What is it? Reading XML is quite simple.

Comment: Well I'm trying to make a program to look at data about stocks and then like trade them, I'm 16 and don't actually expect to acomplish this but I figure I'll learn a lot trying, so I need to get data and then also be able to buy and sell the stocks on this stock market game (www.market watch.com/game). I would be greatful for any useful information about how to do this.

Comment: Can you just tell me/show me specifically which piece of data you want to extract from which page? I can write you the importxml query you need, i use it every day

Comment: I'm trying to get the price from this page
[page](http://finance.yahoo.com/q=goog&fr=uh3_finance_web&uhb=uhb2).Here's a  [screen shot](http://prntscr.com/9fqqa0) with the price circled
it would be useful if you maybe commented your code so I could understand it and then potentially adapt it, thank you!